# Nexus IOS upgrade - pair of 5548's

Tags: cisco-nexus-5k

i need to upgrade the ios for these 2 nexus devices. 
Currently they are running on 6.0.2, how i can check which 7x version should i use ?

```
Software
  BIOS:      version 3.6.0
  loader:    version N/A
  kickstart: version 6.0(2)N2(3)
  system:    version 6.0(2)N2(3)
  Power Sequencer Firmware: 
             Module 1: version v1.0
             Module 2: version v1.0
  Microcontroller Firmware:        version v1.2.0.1
  SFP uC:    Module 1: v1.0.0.0
  QSFP uC:   Module not detected
  BIOS compile time:       05/09/2012
  kickstart image file is: bootflash:///n5000-uk9-kickstart.6.0.2.N2.3.bin
  kickstart compile time:  12/17/2013 2:00:00 [12/17/2013 12:52:59]
  system image file is:    bootflash:///n5000-uk9.6.0.2.N2.3.bin
  system compile time:     12/17/2013 2:00:00 [12/17/2013 16:02:31]


Hardware
  cisco Nexus5548 Chassis ("O2 32X10GE/Modular Universal Platform Supervisor")
  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU         with 8253856 kB of memory.
  Processor Board ID FOC16125CZ7

   bootflash:    2007040 kB

Kernel uptime is 993 day(s), 18 hour(s), 36 minute(s), 2 second(s)

Last reset 
  Reason: Unknown
  System version: 6.0(2)N2(3)
  Service: 

plugin
  Core Plugin, Ethernet Plugin
```

Software seems identical, just the second device of the pair has

```
 Power Sequencer Firmware: 
             Module 1: version v1.0
             Module 2: version v1.0
             Module 3: version v5.0
```

Comment: You need to look at kickstart and the system image. Everything else will be updated if necessary by the system when it reboots.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

On a Nexus environment you need to update both kickstart and system image when upgrading to a whole new software train. Currently version 7.1(4)N1(1) is safe harbor.

Under hardware, you can see which specific version, your Nexus is and thereby find the correct software on Cisco download center.

```
Hardware
  cisco Nexus5548 Chassis ("O2 32X10GE/Modular Universal Platform Supervisor")
```

I looked for **Nexus5548** and since all different versions of the same switch uses the same software, it's pretty straight forward.

Installation is carried out like this for both kickstart and system:

```
install all kickstart ftp: system ftp:
```

You can use several different forms of transfer to the switch. I just added ftp as an example.
Upgrading the software will automatically upgrade any modules or other hardware on the switch. The system will decide if an upgrade is necessary. Typically it's done if a module has bugged firmware or lacks security features or bugs etc. The upgrade procedure is carried out upon reboot by the software upgrade process.

**Kickstart.**
[image: Kickstart]

**System.**
[image]

The star symbol besides the software indicates that Cisco has marked it as safe harbor and therefore is safe to use. You should always stick to safe harbor software.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i checked one by one the tables "Table 2 Upgrade/Downgrade Impact" and i saw the latest version i can upgrade is 7.0(7)N1(1) - if i go in a newer version of this, its not supporting upgrade from current  version  6.0(2)N2(3) 

Link for 7.0(7)N1(1) is:
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5500/sw/upgrade/707_N1_1/n5500_upgrade_downgrade_700.html

and if you try to check the next link of the list that goes to 7.0(8)N1(1),  6.0(2)N2(3)  is not inside.

Comment: Full list is:
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/switches/nexus-5000-series-switches/products-installation-guides-list.html#anchor7

Comment: @Mars The upgrade from-to list is only if you want to use ISSU (In service software upgrade). If you just want to upgrade so can still do a full upgrade, but your systems will not be available when the system restarts.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes i want to do upgrade without timewindow for downtime., so i guess i need to go from the list, maximum ios upgrade 7.0(7)N1(1).

Another very important question is how do i know if i need to upgrade the power controller also ?

Comment: @Mars the power controller will be upgraded by the system if it's necessary, when you initiate the upgrade procedure. Firmware for all modules and controllers are in the system and/or kickstart package.

Comment: The reason i am asking is that some collegues hit bug CSCun66310 - Nexus 5596: System fails to boot after a power cycle.

And they had to follow some steps to resolve it.

"Workaround:To avoid this issue, power controller settings of the Nexus 5596 switch need to be upgraded. It requires to load a debug plugin and run a script. Contact Cisco TAC for further help/directions."


More Info:The issue is only seen on N5K-C5596UP, N5K-C5596T and UCS-FI-6296UP, Nexus 50x0 and Nexus 5548s are NOT affected.

Comment: @Mars Well it is definitely not something i've ever heard about, but give me a few minutes and i'll check with our CCIE.

Comment: PS. whats wrong with this site's text editor? when i press enter to change the line it submits the message and also its loosing all the paragraph formating, making my message to you very difficult to be read and also there is character limit :(

Comment: @Mars he says, that the Nexus 5548 upgrade procedure will upgrade everything as needed. You could be asked to turn off and turn on  the power supply, but it will give you all the information when running the `install all` command.

Comment: @Mars oh i did not see you already found that out.. :-)

Comment: @Mars if you like my answer i hope you will consider marking it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so theoritically i transfer the nx ios to the flash drive and i am ready to upgrade from  6.0(2)N2(3) to 7.0(7)N1(1) without upgrading manual the power controller, by using these commands:http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/nexus-5000-series-switches/112158-nexus5000config-00.html

Comment: Yes you transfer the new ios to the bootflash: and then initialize the install all.

Comment: And there is no problem that there is this difference between these 2 cluster members? 
Member 1:
 Power Sequencer Firmware: 
             Module 1: version v1.0
             Module 2: version v1.0

Member 2:
 Power Sequencer Firmware: 
             Module 1: version v1.0
             Module 2: version v1.0
             Module 3: version v5.0

Comment: @Mars No that is not a problem, but if you are so unsure, maybe you SHOULD arrange for a planned downtime slot, just in case?